# Can't read html source of MAPIMessage

Tags: java, outlook, apache-poi

I have msg file which have html mark up if I view it using Outlook "view source". How can I get this markup using java (what happens when I press view source?)? As far as I see MAPIMessage from apache.poi is useless in this case.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the [getHtmlBody()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hsmf/MAPIMessage.html#getHmtlBody%28%29) method on [MAPIMessage](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hsmf/MAPIMessage.html) - that should give you a single String back containing the HTML source (if present)

Comment: it throws ChunkNotFoundException. And as I understand even if this chunk would exist it would contain html that is produced by Outlook not the original body.

Comment: If you get ChunkNotFound then your message doesn't contain the HTML, sorry. It's possible that Outlook is generating HTML on the fly from RTF, try looking for the compressed Rtf chunk